# Sphinx not returning results in some cases

Tags: sphinx

I'm using extended2 match mode. Here is an example:

```
Keyword 'méz': 0 results
Keyword 'mézes': 4657 results
```

Charset is in utf-8, and min_word_len is 3.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have é in your charset table?

Comment: No, didn't found out how to add MB chars, only found some regex A-Z, a-z, etc... Can you help me please in an answer?

Comment: The wiki http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/ has some information about charset_table